# Automatically change background color in MS word table cells depending on user input in cell

Tags: vba, sharepoint, ms-word, onchange

I have a word file where, which stores information from a SharePoint site into a document. I need to use word (instead of Excel for instance, where conditional formatting would easily fix this problem). There are a few tables in my word document, which gets automatically information from a SharePoint site. However, I would like to get some of the cells background colored if the input value in the cell is "Scheduled" -> Yellow, "Under Work" -> Blue & "Finished" -> Green.

I have Office 2016 O365 in use, which then automatically generates a pdf of the word file after all data is stored, which is then finally sent to different users. I have a working code for the background color change but it always needs to be executed instead of doing this automatically when the cell value changes. Can anyone please help me to rewrite the attached code to work automatically instead of needed to be manually executed every time. I can't find an answer to this problem so hopefully someone here can provide me with a solution.

```
Sub ColorCells()
Dim oTbl As Table
Dim oCel As Cell
Dim oRng As Range
For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
For Each oCel In oTbl.Range.Cells
Set oRng = oCel.Range
    oRng.End = oRng.End - 1
    Select Case oRng.Text
        Case "Scheduled"
            oCel.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdYellow
        Case "Under Work"
            oCel.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdTurquoise
        Case "Finished"
            oCel.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
        Case Is <> "Scheduled"
            oCel.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
        Case Is <> "Under Work"
            oCel.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
        Case Is <> "Finished"
            oCel.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
End Select
Next
Next
End Sub
```

I expect to get all the cells background colored, with the text "Scheduled", "Under Work" & "Finished" to Yellow, Blue & Green. All the other cells with some other information stored should be without any background color.

Comment: I know of no event in Word that triggers when document content is "updated". Can you tell us what technology is used to link(?) the table content to SharePoint? Or describe the steps in the UI to achieve it?

Comment: I use tags from SharePoint like {{v.status}} etc. that are also stated in the Word document. When we generate a report from SharePoint the system checks into our Word template, changes {{v.status}} to "Scheduled", "Under Work" or "Finished" depending on its status in SharePoint and then finally generates a pdf of everything in the Word file. The only problem I seem to have is that I can't get the background color changed into our final document. In Excel I would do it via Conditional Formatting but I could not find a similar solution to do it in Word and therefore some VBA code written.

Comment: You say "report is generated" - so a new document (dicx( is generated from a template (dotx or dotm)? Perhaps code in a macro that runs when a new document is created might help? (if the updating is fast enough...)

Comment: Thanks Cindy, I'll try that. Otherwise I need to find some other solution.